# Hora no Mysql e PHP

Tags: php

Seguinte gente to com uma `current_date` no `MySQL` e me retorna o dia do cadastro só que no formato do banco : `2017-01-06`.

Como faço para deixar no formato: ***sexta, 06 de janeiro de 2017***.

Para exibição dos meus dados no banco eu uso

```
<?php echo $row->data; ?>
```

Exibir ela em português fiz mas com a 
echo strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime($date)); 
Ele me retorna todos as datas no dia 31 de Dezembro de 1969.
Se eu ponho
echo strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime('today'));
Todas ficam com o dia de hoje.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$date = $row->data;
echo strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Já sim, ele me dá todos com uma mesma data, o formato até funciona mas a data vem 31 de Dezembro de 1969.

Comment: Se eu por   com a strtotime('today'));  Ele me dá a data atual mas a questão é que eu não quero exibir o dia de hoje em todos os post eu quero exibir a data em que ele foi postado.  Testei em um post antigo e me deu a data de hoje.

Comment: Normalmente quando a data vem 31/12/1969 é por que houve uma falha ao converter a data. Como está vindo a data do seu banco? É um campo DATE? (yyyy/mm/dd)

Comment: Sim está num campos no SQL mas no envio para o banco ele pega o dia exato através de uma current_date